# How can I change the background color of horizontal bar if date value is less than to current date?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, gantt-chart

I want to change the background color of horizontal bar in highcharts(gantt chart) if the date value is less than to current date? Please take a look on the picture: https://ibb.co/3MNqJJy and this is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/57n1cjyr/

```
var today = new Date().getTime(),
  day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var options = {
    title: {
      text: 'Visual Planner Chart with Navigation',
    },
    xAxis: currentDateIndicator: true,
    min: today - 3 * day,
    max: today + 18 * day
  },
  yAxis: {
    uniqueNames: true

  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Visual Planner',
    data: [],
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      format: '{point.owner}'
    }
  }]
}

var ganttChart = Highcharts.ganttChart('container-ganttChart', options)

ganttChart.series[0].addPoint({
  start: Date.UTC(2019, 01, 30),
  end: Date.UTC(2019, 03, 01),
  name: 'crewRank',
  owner: 'crewName'
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `start`  and `today` specified as in the code above, this seems to work (replace the last part with it, the other code is unmodified):

```
    var startDate=Date.UTC(2019, 01, 30)
    // call gantt chart then add series
    ganttChart.series[0].addPoint({
        start: startDate,
        end: Date.UTC(2019, 03, 01),
        name: 'crewRank',
        owner: 'crewName',
        color:  new Date(startDate).getTime() < today ? 'red' :'blue'
    }
```

The color is red or blue depending on the current date value